# Radio button is not returning it's status to Apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm new to salesforce and trying to get list of all related contacts to an Account when corresponding radio button is clicked.
Here is my VF code

```
<input type="radio" value="{!w.status}" name="any">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!getAllcont}" reRender="rr"/>
            </input>{!w.status}      

            <!--
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!w.status}">
            <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!getAllcont}"/>
            </apex:inputCheckbox> -->
```

The same code is working perfectly with the `<apex:inputCheckbox>`(code in comments) but return false with  `<input type="radio">`

My Apex Class code is

```
public void getAllcont(){
        con = new List<Contact>();
        for(wrapperaccount w:wr){
            system.debug(w.status +''+w.ac.Id);
            if(w.status==true){
                con.add([select id,accountid,firstname,lastname from contact where accountid=:w.ac.Id]);
            }
        }
    }
```

In Debug window it shows *status=false* for all records(with html input tag only)

Please guide me what's wrong I'm doing or missing.

Comment: what is rr? Can you post more code?

Comment: rr is the id of apexpageBlock. I can share but it will be too lengthy and I don't think there is any problem with other part of the code. If I uncomment the commented code it will work perfectly(obviously commenting the uncommented code).

Comment: Is there a reason you really want to use regular html input instead of the visualforce tag?

Comment: hi Folkert, I tried a little using apex:selectradion tag, but not comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because HTML tags don't support data binding in Visualforce. You need to use Apex tags to pass data from page to controller. You need to use [apex:selectRadio](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm) to get selected value back in controller.

Or use `apex:actionfunction` with `param` to pass data in controller.

Comment: I do tried apex:selectRadio but we need to add Apex:selectoption with it. Which shows radio button(s) grouped row wise. But I want it to be Column wise. Also I triedapex:actionfucntion called on radio button click. But nothing woking

Comment: @VDahiya In apex:actionfunction what error you are facing?

Comment: Error using actionFunction with param

Error: <apex:actionFunction> may not be used within an iterable component. You can use <apex:param> to define parameters for the function and pass iteration-specific values via the parameters.

Comment: @VDahiya Error is correct. Decalre this outside repeat tag and then call it using JavaScript

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still it's not working.

Comment: @VDahiya Saying not working will not help. Paste the updated code and what erro you are facing.